# Image doesn't store in Laravel 6

Tags: laravel, vue.js, laravel-6

I've tried to implement `image upload` in Laravel using Vue.js? However, I didn't know why the image doesn't save to the database. I'm not sure, the real problem comes from within my `Vue.js` or `My Controller`. I still, can't figure out how.

**CustomerController**

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $data = $request->validate([
        'name' => 'required',
        'email' => 'required',
        'phone' => 'required',
        'company_name' => 'required',
    ]);

    $customer = Customer::create($data);

    if ($request->hasFile('image')) {
        $image = $request->get('image');
        $imageName = time().'.'.$request->image->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $request->image->move(public_path('images'), $imageName);
    }
    // dd($customer);

    return response()->json(['sucessfully created image']);
}
```

Comment: why you don't debug the code to figure out the issue source?

Comment: @Shrembo is my controller right or wrong?

Comment: @CamBoKiDz in vuejs u should use base64 to upload image

Comment: Do you intend to save the image file in the database or just the image filename?

Answer (score 0):

I think you forget ti save the image

Try this

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $data = $request->validate([
        'name' => 'required',
        'email' => 'required',
        'phone' => 'required',
        'company_name' => 'required',
    ]);

    $customer = Customer::create($data);

    if ($request->hasFile('image')) {
        $image = $request->get('image');
        $imageName = time().'.'.$request->image->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $request->image->move(public_path('images'), $imageName);
        // Get the property name of table I suppose its imgData
        $customer->imgData = $imageName;
        $customer->save();
    }

    return response()->json(['sucessfully created image']);
}
```

OR if you have many to many relationship
simply replace that line with attach method
Let me know if this helps you

Comment: i got this ` Call to a member function getClientOriginalExtension() on string`

Comment: @Bipin Me too!!